# Unmarshalling JSON array via Jettison/Resteasy

Tags: json, resteasy, jettison

Ran into a similar problem like the following forum post:

http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/parsing-JSON-with-Arrays-using-Jettison-td5732207.html

Using Resteasy 2.0.1GA with Jettison 1.2 and getting a problem marshalling arrays when involving namespace mappings.  See code below.  Basically if the number of array entries are greater than one and namespace mappings are used.  Anybody else run into this problem?  The Nabble form poster got around it by writing a custom unmarshaller.

I either need to isolate the Jettison bug or write a Resteasy extension of the JettisonMappedUnmarshaller class (which hands over the namespace mappings and unmarshaller to the Jettison Configuration).

The following code doesn't unmarshall (post step) if the properties variables contains 2 or more entries.

```
public class Experimenting {

    @Path("test")
    public static class MyResource {
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "Property", propOrder = { "name", "value" })
        public static class MyProperty {
            @XmlElement(name = "Name", required = true)
            protected String name;
            @XmlElement(name = "Value", required = true)
            protected String value;

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public String getValue() {
                return value;
            }

            public void setValue(String value) {
                this.value = value;
            }
        }

        @XmlType(name = "MyElement", propOrder = { "myProperty" })
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlRootElement(name = "MyElement", namespace = "http://www.klistret.com/cmdb/ci/commons")
        @Mapped(namespaceMap = { @XmlNsMap(namespace = "http://www.klistret.com/cmdb/ci/commons", jsonName = "com.klistret.cmdb.ci.commons") })
        public static class MyElement {
            @XmlElement(name = "MyProperty", namespace = "http://www.klistret.com/cmdb/ci/commons")
            protected List myProperty;

            public List getMyProperty() {
                if (myProperty == null) {
                    myProperty = new ArrayList();
                }
                return this.myProperty;
            }

            public void setMyProperty(List myProperty) {
                this.myProperty = myProperty;
            }
        }

        @GET
        @Path("myElement/{id}")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public MyElement getMy(@PathParam("id")
        Long id) {
            MyElement myElement = new MyElement();

            MyProperty example = new MyProperty();
            example.setName("example");
            example.setValue("of a property");

            MyProperty another = new MyProperty();
            another.setName("another");
            another.setValue("just a test");

            MyProperty[] properties = new MyProperty[] { example, another };
            myElement.setMyProperty(Arrays.asList(properties));

            return myElement;
        }

        @POST
        @Path("/myElement")
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public MyElement createMy(MyElement myElement) {
            List properties = myElement.getMyProperty();
            System.out.println("Properties size: " + properties.size());

            return myElement;
        }
    }

    private Dispatcher dispatcher;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // embedded server
        dispatcher = MockDispatcherFactory.createDispatcher();
        dispatcher.getRegistry().addPerRequestResource(MyResource.class);

    }

    @Test
    public void getAndCreate() throws URISyntaxException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException {
        MockHttpRequest getRequest = MockHttpRequest.get("/test/element/44");
        MockHttpResponse getResponse = new MockHttpResponse();

        dispatcher.invoke(getRequest, getResponse);
        String getResponseBodyAsString = getResponse.getContentAsString();

        System.out.println(String.format(
                "Get Response code [%s] with payload [%s]", getResponse
                        .getStatus(), getResponse.getContentAsString()));

        MockHttpRequest postRequest = MockHttpRequest.post("/test/element");
        MockHttpResponse postResponse = new MockHttpResponse();

        postRequest.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        postRequest.content(getResponseBodyAsString.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        dispatcher.invoke(postRequest, postResponse);
        System.out.println(String.format(
                "Post Response code [%s] with payload [%s]", postResponse
                        .getStatus(), postResponse.getContentAsString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Using BadgerFish on the Get return and Post parameter/return works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use Jettison? If not I would recommend just switching to use [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) instead; this typically solves array/list related problems (problem with Jettison is that it converts to XML model, which makes it very hard to tell arrays from objects -- there are bugs, too, but it is fundamentally hard thing to get working correctly).

Comment: Underlying annotations are JAXB and Jackson from the little reading I have done supports only a subset of JAXB annotations.  Switched over to Badgerfish with solved the above problem but ran into an issue with unmarshalling string arrays.  :-)  Can marhsall/unmarshall an array of string using Resteasy mock classes locally but via the server the exact same JSON yields a string parser error.  Weird.

Comment: Jackson supports pretty much all annotations that make sense -- many JAXB annotations are XML-specific and do not apply. But only used not supported that I have heard anyone wish have been ones for XmlID. So it's typically not problematic. Further, most of the time, no annotationss are needed (Jackson does have its own set, JAXB is supported but not actually recommended, due to xml-specificity). But if badgerfish works, good. It's butt-ugly, but hey to each his own. :)